# Correctly interpolate 3D vector field with python scipy

Tags: python, vector, scipy, 3d, interpolation

## GOAL

My goal is to interpolate a 3D vector field using python.

## CODE

### Original Vector field

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# For interpolation
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator


#%% VECTOR FIELD

xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

uu = np.sin(np.pi * xx) * np.cos(np.pi * yy) * np.cos(np.pi * zz)
vv = -np.cos(np.pi * xx) * np.sin(np.pi * yy) * np.cos(np.pi * zz)
ww = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * xx) * np.cos(np.pi * yy) *
     np.sin(np.pi * zz))

# Ravel -> make 1D lists

x = np.ravel(xx)
y = np.ravel(yy)
z = np.ravel(zz)

u = np.ravel(uu)
v = np.ravel(vv)
w = np.ravel(ww)
```

[image]

### Interpolation Function (something is wrong here)

```
#%% INTERPOLATION FUNCTION

def interpolate_field(x,y,z,u,v,w,new_points):
    
    x = np.unique(x)
    y = np.unique(y)
    z = np.unique(z)
    
    u = np.reshape(u, (len(x), len(y), len(z)))
    v = np.reshape(u, (len(x), len(y), len(z)))
    w = np.reshape(u, (len(x), len(y), len(z)))
    
    u_int_f = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), u)
    v_int_f = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), v)
    w_int_f = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), w)
    

    u_int = u_int_f(new_points)
    v_int = v_int_f(new_points)
    w_int = w_int_f(new_points)
    
    return u_int, v_int, w_int
```

### Evaluate interpolation at new points

```
#%% EVALUATE INTERPOLATION FUNCTION

new_grid = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 20),
    np.linspace(np.min(y), np.max(y), 20),
    np.linspace(np.min(z), np.max(z), 3)
    , indexing="xy")
            
# create list of new_points
new_points = np.vstack(list(map(np.ravel, new_grid))).T
# get vector field values at new points
uint, vint, wint = interpolate_field(x,y,z,u,v,w,new_points)

new_points = np.array(new_points)
xn = new_points[:,0]
yn = new_points[:,1]
zn = new_points[:,2]

# PLOT
fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.quiver(xn, yn, zn, uint, vint, wint, length=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

## THE ISSUE

As you can see something is wrong with the interpolation function since the resulting vector plot does not show the same behavior as the original at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `RegularGridInterpolator`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator


def interp_field(field, coords, shape):
    interpolator = RegularGridInterpolator(
        (gridZ[:, 0, 0], gridY[0, :, 0], gridX[0, 0, :]), field)
    return interpolator(coords).reshape(shape)


gridZ, gridY, gridX = np.mgrid[-0.8:1:3j, -0.8:1:10j, -0.8:1:10j]

u = np.sin(np.pi * gridX) * np.cos(np.pi * gridY) * np.cos(np.pi * gridZ)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * gridX) * np.sin(np.pi * gridY) * np.cos(np.pi * gridZ)
w = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * gridX) * np.cos(np.pi * gridY) *
     np.sin(np.pi * gridZ))

interp_gridZ, interp_gridY, interp_gridX = np.mgrid[
    -0.8:1:3j, -0.8:1:20j, -0.8:1:20j]
interp_coords = np.column_stack(
    (interp_gridZ.flatten(), interp_gridY.flatten(), interp_gridX.flatten()))
interp_u = interp_field(u, interp_coords, interp_gridX.shape)
interp_v = interp_field(v, interp_coords, interp_gridX.shape)
interp_w = interp_field(w, interp_coords, interp_gridX.shape)

fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'),
                             constrained_layout=True)
ax.quiver(gridX, gridY, gridZ, u, v, w, length=0.3)
bx.quiver(interp_gridX, interp_gridY, interp_gridZ,
          interp_u, interp_v, interp_w, length=0.3)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot looks like that:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you tell me what exactly is different from my implementation?  Mores specifically, what were the major reasons for which my approach failed?

Comment: I believe `indexing` should have been `ij` in both your `meshgrid` calls for the rest to work as expected. Also, using `ravel` and `reshape` on the velocity components caused problems.